# How to parse a firebase object (JSON Object)

Tags: json, angular, typescript, firebase

I have an fire object `obj`. 
I `JSON.stringify(obg)`ed the object and it gives

```
{"12:23:34:45":{"Brand":"Sams","Carrier":"Car 1"},"23:34:45:56":{"Brand":"Sams","Carrier":"Car 2"}}
```

Beautified version is

```
{
"12:23:34:45":
    {
    "Brand":"Sams",
    "Carrier":"Car 1"
    },
"23:34:45:56":
    {"Brand":"Sams",
    "Carrier":"Car 2"
    }
}
```

What I have tried is to loop through this object to get the Carriers but it failed

```
for(let i in obj){
  console.log(i.Carrier);
}
```

I want to get the keys (`12:23:34:45` and `23:34:45:56`) from this object but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need lopp here, just use **[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**

```js
var myObj = {"12:23:34:45":{"Brand":"Sams","Carrier":"Car 1"},"23:34:45:56":{"Brand":"Sams","Carrier":"Car 2"}};

console.log( Object.keys(myObj));
```

Comment: Thanks man a lot :), was struggling for a few hours. Thanks again!